# How can I create a file that can be accessed by any user?

Tags: c#, .net

My software needs to generate files on the filesystem that can be read by any other instance of my program, regardless of the user account it's running under. The problem I'm having is that if a file is created under an admin account then I run into an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when trying to read the contents of the file under a different account. Here's the code I'm using to create the file

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    streamWriter.Write(/*some data*/);
}
```

and to read from the file

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    var idLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
    if (idLine != null) fileContents = idLine;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the access to your file, you have to use the AccessControl : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c13ttb3.aspx

Comment: Do you happen to know what kind of access control permissions are required for my reading method? It seems to fail if I give "Everyone" Read permission but succeeds if I give "Everyone" full control, which is not ideal.

Comment: If you look at this article, you can give the Read access which includes some other read access : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Call [`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) to get an application specific path which is accessible (read/write etc.) by all users/accounts on that computer.

Comment: That's not what I asked. The files need to be written wherever the writing application has permission and readable wherever they are written.

Comment: I'll remove the downvote because I should have been more clear. Sorry, it has been a heck of a day.

Comment: @MartinDoms to answer your question it would help to know what you mean by "wherever they are written" since it might differ in what has to be done (for example the Programs directory is a "special case")...

Comment: Well the user can instruct this program to work on any directory on the filesystem. As long as the user has write permission then the program will write where the user tells it to. I just need to be able to read whatever I write. It looks like the above answer has solved my problems, although for some reason I need to give the "Everyone" user group write access, simple read access doesn't work.

Comment: @MartinDoms I understand but you should be aware that allowing to write anywhere in the filesystem and changing permissions accordingly creates potential security issuess...